# android facebook sdk always asking for login on restart

Tags: android, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

i've implemented facebook login with 4.0 sdk, after succesful login, i get an accees token and continue to the main activity and everything works perfect.
But when i close and reopen the app, accesstoken is null. i dont know how to fix it

Here is my code:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        FacebookSdk.setIsDebugEnabled(true);
        FacebookSdk.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);
    }


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_fb);



    prefs =  getSharedPreferences("config", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = prefs.edit();

    token_session = "";


    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();

    accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldAccessToken, AccessToken newAccessToken) {
            AccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(newAccessToken);

            updateWithToken(newAccessToken);
        }
    };

    accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();

    updateWithToken(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken());

    accessTokenTracker.startTracking();
    startApp();

}
private void startApp(){
    loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);

    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            AccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());

            sendLoginToBackend();
            //Log.i("Facebook Login", loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken());

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            //Log.i("Facebook Login", "Login Cancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            Log.e("Facebook Login", "Login Error");
        }
    });


}
private void updateWithToken(AccessToken currentAccessToken) {

    if (currentAccessToken == null){
        Log.i("Facebook Access Token ","null");
    }else{
        Log.i("Facebook Access Token ","not null");
    }

    if (currentAccessToken != null) {

        if (prefs.getBoolean("datos_completos",false)){
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
               // THIS WILL BE REMOVED
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //Intent i = new Intent(self, MainActivity.class);
                    //startActivity(i);
                    //finish();
                }
            }, 500);
        }
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this,"NO FB TOKEN",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are calling logout every time in the Activity's onCreate method.

```
 LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```

Comment: Wow!!  how could I not see this line!!?? i guess i was too troubled for the deadline that didnt read all the code! I'm so sorry! Thank you! ..... I dont deserve to be called programmer anymore.

Answer (score 0):

just remove this line

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```

calling logout method on onCreate method means that you are logged out from facebook every time the application starts.